# jQuery error with Grails and Netbeans

Tags: jquery, grails, netbeans

I have a Grails (2.1.1) app which I have developed using Netbeans (7.2) and I have included some JavaScript in one of the GSP pages.  It works fine when I run it up on localhost via Netbeans, but when I package it up as a WAR and deploy it I am getting a

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

error.

My page has the necessary

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> javascript stuff </script>
```

I thought it was because Netbeans wasn't packaging jQuery up correctly, so I included jquery-1.11.2.min.js in my js folder (along with application.js) but still no joy.

Comment: Post how you are including the jquery file and your custom js file.

Comment: Ah. (I did say I was a newbie!).  I don't have a custom js file. I have simply added the javascript to the gsp page.  I  was kind of assuming Netbeans would take care of including all the necessary files for me, but I guess not.

Comment: So please post which code is not working replace the 'javascript stuff' with the actual code.

Comment: Ah, right. sorry.  Well, the offending line is  $("#termSiteText").text(listItems[1]);  where  termSitetext  is from <td> <p id="termSiteText">${termInstance.site[0]}</p></td>

Comment: Try ` jQuery("#termSiteText").text(listItems[1]); `

Comment: Ahhh... ok. I fixed it.  I used document.getElementById('termSiteText').innerHTML = listItems[1];  and it works fine.   Thanks for the suggestion anyway.